# How to turn on HTC One Mini with a broken power button?

Tags: htc

My power button is broken, and unfortunately you cannot take the battery out to turn it on like I seen in youtube tutorials, therefore Im seeking for anyones help to tell me how to turn it on? I also tried the volume keys; don't work...

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately adb wont help if the phone is switched off completely. Did you try plugging it in charger or connecting to pc?

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's no other way than opening the case and manually shorting out power button pins for 1 - 2 secs.

It's not that hard, I've done that with my HTC Desire before. :) Just google for "disassemble HTC One Mini"

Just one tip: If the case refuses to open, **do not try too hard**, maybe you're just doing it wrong, think first, then do, **it should open easily** without putting much pressure and power 
Good luck